# JAXB Custom Bindings to generate Constants

Tags: jaxb, xjc, onix

I'm generating Java classes from a xsd file provided by a 3rd party (the ONIX XML file XSD to be precise). The schema defines quite a few types, that have a `shortname` and a `refname` attribute. Unfortunately, the ONIX guys did not set the single allowed string value for those fields, using the `fixed` attribute, but instead they did it like this:

```xml
<xs:attribute name="refname">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="AddresseeIDType"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>

<xs:attribute name="shortname">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="m380"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

This causes JAXB to generate mutable String field's for the shortname and refname property. The information about the only valid values for those fields is lost during the class generation process.

Is there any way to use an external JAXB bindings file to have XJC generate the fields for `shortname` and `refname` in the following form:

```java
@XmlAttribute(name = "refname")
protected static final String refname = "AddresseeIDType";

@XmlAttribute(name = "shortname")
protected static final String shortname = "m380";
```

I know there is a `fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty` attribute, but that does only seem to work, if the xsd would instead define the `shortname` and `refname` in the following manner:

```xml
<xs:attribute name="refname" fixed="AddresseeIDType" />
<xs:attribute name="shortname" fixed="m380" />
```

Any help appreciated